# implementing jump register (jr, sll, slti) in multicycle

Tags: mips, cycle, fsm

I've been asked to sketch a multicycle datapath and control unit for the instructions (js, sll, slti) all together. and draw the main controller FSM for these 3 instructions.

I'm struggle with it, I know how to make it with single cycle datapath but not for multicycle.

please, help

Answer (score 0):

If you know the single cycle datapath, and want to take that to multi cycle, generally speaking we subdivide the single cycle into stages.

As only one stage will execute at a time, a relatively simple state machine controls what stage to execute currently/next to activate the appropriate stage, and deactivate the others.

The stages would be similar to the stages of a pipelined processor, namely those corresponding to Instruction Fetch, Decode, Execute, Memory, and Writeback.

In a pipelined machine, all the instructions need to go through all the stages, however, in a multicycle machine, certain instructions can skip certain states, and this should be manifest in the state machine.  For example, while all instructions share Instruction Fetch and Decode, only loads and stores interact with the Data Memory, so any other instruction can skip the Mem stage.

The simplest possible state machine simply chooses all the states in succession, for every instruction, without ever consulting the instruction.  This would fail to take advantage of the ability to skip stages for certain instructions that don't need those stages, and of course, you're being asked to do more than the simplest state machine.

A better state machine might start with Instruction Fetch as the active state, go to Decode state next, and by then it can use knowledge of the actual instruction to decide which of the remaining stages to skip for that given instruction.

You can imagine that the Control logic fetches some bits that inform the state machine of which stages can be skipped for any given opcode.  There are only three states/stages left, so all that is needed from Control is a boolean for each.

For more information, especially on the stages and what they do, I suggest searching on Pipelined/Pipelining MIPS, as I believe there is more material on pipelined processors than on the multicycle design.  You won't be concerned with pipeline hazzards, but the break down of the single cycle design into the stages might help.